How to construct a harmonious labeling function?
I'm building code for harmonious labeling on Hanoi H_2 graph.
When I run the code there there is a repetition of edge labels and vertex labels used are not from 0 to 11 even though the requirement of harmonic labeling is that vertices can be labeled from 0 to q-1 (where q is the number of graph edges, which means the number of Hanoi H_2 graph edges is 12). Is there something wrong with my code?
from random import sample

H2 = nx.Graph()
H2.add_edges_from([(1 ,2), (2 ,3), (3 ,1), (2 ,4), (4 ,5), (5 ,6), (6 ,4),
           (6 ,8), (3 ,7), (7 ,8), (8 ,9), (9 ,7)])

plt.figure()

# set random node
node_labels = {node: i for i, node in enumerate(sample(list(H2), H2.number_of_nodes()))}
nx.set_node_attributes(H2, node_labels, 'label')

pos = nx.spring_layout(H2)
nx.draw(H2, pos, edge_color='black', width=1, linewidths=2,
    node_size=500, node_color='#add8e6', alpha=1, labels=node_labels)

# Harmonious label for the edges
edge_labels = {(u, v): (node_labels[u] + node_labels[v]) % (H2.number_of_edges()) for u, v in H2.edges}
nx.set_edge_attributes(H2, edge_labels, 'label')


You have to define what you mean by "harmonious", of course if you use (u+v) % n as label, you will have collisions (you would even with just u+v or ...%n)

sorry, Harmonic labeling of a graph G with q edges is defined as a one-on-one mapping f from the set of vertices in the graph G to Z_q where Z_q is an integer notation modulo q, such that for each uv ∈ E(G) we have f* (uv)=(f(u)+f(v))(mod q), where f* is the edge label function in the graph G and uv is the edge connecting vertices u and v.

Let's assume an edge between 2 and 3 and one between 1 and 4, both give the same sum (1+4 = 2+3 = 5). How would you possibly have a unique edge label? The modulo adds another level of collision, assuming two different sums (e.g. 5 and 14) for 9 nodes, then the sum modulo 9 is 5 for both. Must you really use (u+v)%q?

yes because that is the rule of harmonic labeling so I have to find any pair of numbers that will get a unique label if I use (u+v)%q.

I see, then you should most likely rewrite your question. It's not about networkx, it's about this specific problem of finding u/v pairs that match your constraint. In fact I even think this question is offtopic on SO and should rather be asked on https://math.stackexchange.com/
